# What is $\lim_{n \to \infty} e^{-n} f(n)$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence that converges to $a$. And $f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{a_k x^k}{k!}$

From previous parts, I know that $e^{-x}f(x) -a= e^{-x} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(a_k-a) x^k}{k!}$

Prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} e^{-n} f(n)$ exists and find its value.

I'm having a lot of trouble with this. For one I'm not sure what the limit is. I thought mabey the limit is 0 but I got stuck:

$|e^{-n}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{a_k n^k}{k!} - 0|=|e^{-n}| *|\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{a_k n^k}{k!}| \leq |e^{-n}| * |A|\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} |n^k/k!|$ where A is bound for $a_n.$ Then  $\leq |e^{-n}|*|A|e^{-n} = |A|$. But that wouldn't be $< \epsilon.$

Then I though maybe it converges to a because from previous part we have $e^{-x}f(x) =a+ e^{-x} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(a_k-a) x^k}{k!}$. Then

$|a+ e^{-n} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(a_k-a) n^k}{k!} -a| = |e^{-n} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(a_k-a) n^k}{k!}| \leq |e^{-n}|*\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} |\frac{(a_k-a) n^k}{k!}| \leq |e^{-n}| * |2A| \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} |\frac{n^k}{k!}| \leq |2A|$. But again not not sure how to make it $< \epsilon.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $a_n\to a$ as $n\to\infty$, for $\forall \epsilon>0$, there is $N_1\in\mathrm N$ and $M>0$ such that
$$ |a_n-a|<\epsilon/2, \forall n> N_1 $$
and
$$ |a_n-a|\le M, \forall n>0. $$
So
\begin{eqnarray}
|e^{-n}f(n)-a|&\le& e^{-n} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{|a_k-a| n^k}{k!}\\
&=&e^{-n} \sum_{k=0}^{N_1} \frac{|a_k-a| n^k}{k!}+e^{-n} \sum_{k=N_1+1}^{\infty} \frac{|a_k-a| n^k}{k!}\\
&\le& Me^{-n} \sum_{k=0}^{N_1} \frac{n^k}{k!}+\frac12\epsilon e^{-n} \sum_{k=N_1+1}^{\infty} \frac{n^k}{k!}\\
&\le& Me^{-n} \sum_{k=0}^{N_1} \frac{n^k}{k!}+\frac12\epsilon e^{-n} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{n^k}{k!}\\
&\le& Me^{-n}\sum_{k=0}^{N_1} \frac{n^k}{k!}+\frac12\epsilon. \end{eqnarray}
Since $\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{-n}\sum_{k=0}^{N_1} \frac{n^k}{k!}=0$ for fixed $N_1$, there is $N_2>0$ such that
$$ e^{-n}\sum_{k=0}^{N_1} \frac{n^k}{k!}<\frac{\epsilon}{2M}, \forall n>N_2. $$
Let $N=\max\{N_1,N_2\}$. Then for $n>N$,
$$ |e^{-n}f(n)-a|<\frac12\epsilon+\frac12\epsilon=\epsilon, \forall n>N. $$
Namely
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}e^{-n}f(n)=a. $$

Comment: Is the $e^{-N_1}$ a typo? Shouldn't it be $e^{-n}$ since you are just distributing the $e^{-n}$? Also $\sum_{k=N_1 +1}^{\infty} \frac{|a_k -a| n^k}{k!}$ equals $e^n$ even though we don't start from $k=0$?

Comment: This a typo. See the update.

Answer (score 0):

For a constant sequence $a_n = a$ we have $f(n)e^{-n} = a$. So one might suspect that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} f(n)e^{-n} = a = \lim_{k \to \infty} a_k\, .
$$
holds also in the general case.

That is indeed true. The “trick” is to split the series into two parts, one finite part and an infinite part whose terms are known to be small.

For given $\epsilon > 0$ there is an index $K$ such that $|a_k - a| < \epsilon$ for all $k > K$. Then
$$
 |f(n)e^{-n} - a| \le e^{-n}\left | \sum_{k=0}^K \frac{(a_k-a) n^k}{k!}\right| + \epsilon e^{-n} \sum_{k=K+1}^\infty \frac{n^k}{k!} \le \sum_{k=0}^K \frac{|a_k - a| n^k}{k!e^n} + \epsilon 
$$
It follows that
$$
 \limsup_{n \to \infty} |f(n)e^{-n} - a| \le \epsilon
$$
because $e^n$ grows faster than any polynomial. This holds for all $\epsilon > 0$, so that $\limsup_{n \to \infty} |f(n)e^{-n} - a| = 0$, i.e.
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} f(n)e^{-n} = a \, .
$$